# Airline not offering re-routing as per EU 261/2004

Tags: european-union, air-travel

### Context:

My parents had a reservation for a flight made of 3 segments (all part of the same booking and sold by the same airline), the first one departing from within the EU and with a final destination outside the EU. The first segment departed with a delay of around 1 hour, which meant they missed segments 2 and 3. They bought another ticket with the same airline (more on this below) and reached the final destination with a total delay of 10+ hours.

According to [regulation 261/2004](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261&qid=1706374829448) article 3 paragraph 1/a, they should be covered by said regulation.

### Questions:

I believe that they can:

1. claim for a compensation, according to article 7 paragraph 1/c.
2. Since no employee/representative from the airline offered re-routing (article 8, paragraph 1), despite my parents insisting that they should be offered an alternative flight at no extra cost, I believe the airline breached article 14. Because of that, my parents had to pay $1000+ to reach the intended final destination (by the way, with the same airline). Since the airline breached article 14, I believe my parents are entitled to claim the cost of rebooking back. Would you agree?

Comment: Why, at the time they were preparing to purchase the second set of tickets, didn't they stop once availability was confirmed, and before they paid, and insist that the agent book them under the original ticket?  Something isn't adding up here...

Comment: They just didn’t know. They told me they did the same with another person who was on the same flight

Comment: Normally if you don’t know about a regulation it’s your fault, but in this case the airline had the obligation to inform them of their rights, which they failed to do, otherwise why would my parents have paid for another flight to get to the same destination?

Comment: But you are saying that "*they just didn't know*" and also "*despite my parents insisting that they should be offered an alternative flight*".  Those statements are incongruous.  Apparently the airline did offer an alternative flight, which your parents chose to pay for.  I feel for them if they are elderly, and I'm not saying the airline might not have violated something, but the question is still unclear on what actually transpired.  Article 14 just says they have to post a notice, and provide a written copy in the event of a delay *when asked*.

Comment: I see what you mean. I wasn’t there so I can only report their story, but basically they got to the check in counter, said their flight was delayed and missed a connection. The employee gave them another ticket and then they were asked to pay. They questioned why, as the delay wasn’t their fault (the flight was already delayed at departure) but in the end they weren’t offered any other solution. In particular, at no point were they offered any compensation or free alternative flight (art. 7 & 8). I think you’re right re art. 14, I don’t know if they actually violated it at this point